# Ambiguity of the "RC" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Apparently the [rc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rc) is used for both "remote-control" and "resistor-capacitor". I think we should do away with the ambiguous [rc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rc) and use more explicit tags instead. For the first one [remote-control](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) looks like an obvious choice, but I'm having my doubts about [resistor-capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resistor-capacitor). Keeping [rc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rc) for this is not a good idea, because the quadcopters will also use it; I don't think the description excerpt is much read.

So, 1) incinerate [rc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rc) and 2) find a good name for "resistor-capacitor".

Comment: I always thought it meant *Regular Circuit* as apposed to *Integrated Circuit* (IC).  I guess we should file a Request for Consideration with the Research Committee.

Comment: I think "passive components" (or just "passives") would do fine, otherwise we could end up with an exponentially increasing number of component combinations!

Comment: I thought they were talking about the soda :)

Comment: Do we have numbers on how many of those questions are resistor-capacitor and how many are remote-control?

Comment: @Kortuk - No, but we will in a while :-). I'll report back.

Comment: Just makes a difference in what I need to do behind the scenes to possibly make some of this easier. Thanks for figuring it out for me :)

Comment: @Kortuk - 12 resistor-capacitor, 20 remote control (*all* of them toys, so nothing about rc-5 or so. May be relevant). BTW , half of the RC-5 questions are tagged "ir" instead.

Answer (score 5):

*Posting as an answer so we can see how much support there is for this. (you can't downvote a comment. Not that this would be an invitation for downvotes! :-))*

I would suggest [passive-networks](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-networks) for the resistor-capacitor. Applies to a number of existing questions too, like [this typical one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34965/kirchoff-law-in-ac-circuit).

Comment: I'm fine with "passives" or "passive networks", but how are new users to this site going to think of looking for those?  "RC" or "resistor" and "capacitor" would make sense from their point of view, and they wouldn't go looking for "passives" or maybe not even know what that means.

Comment: @Olin - I agree, and it's a general problem. Last week I had to edit a question about a relay module with 4 tags, but "relay" was not one of them. That's where the incineration comes in. Blacklist a tag, and they will *have* to think further. Maybe we need a heuristic system which can propose tags based on terms appearing in the question.

Comment: Having a 'rc' tag for RC circuits (resistor capacitor) is not surprising giving that all the books talk about "RC" circuits (and LR, CL too). How about "rc-circuit"? I find the tag for that kind of circuits useful.

Answer (score 4):

As a self confessed misambiguist (sorry, someone just *had* to invent that word :) I *totally* agree. [remote-control](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control) sounds fine and is preferable to [radio-control](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-control) in my opinion since it is more general.

For the same reason, I would suggest [passive-components](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-components) or just [passives](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passives) for questions relating to resistor/capacitor networks.

Comment: "passives" is good enough for me, the components aren't needed AKAIC. Oddly enough, neither of them exists yet.

Comment: Or maybe "passive-networks"? We have a tag for resistors and a few capacitors already.

Comment: @stevenvh - that sounds OK to me. I didn't realize we had so many capacitor tags. A question relating to "aluminium electrolytic decoupling capacitors" could get 4 tags!! (by the way, AKAIC??).

Comment: As *Kar* :-) As I'm Concerned. You must have heard it before ;-)

Comment: @stevenvh - Just spent 5 minutes googling it. Feel like a right idiot now :(

Comment: Sorry pal!......

Comment: The main concern that I have with using [tag:remote-control] as a synonym for [tag:radio-control] is that you start mixing toy car questions with television questions. Not the end of the world, but I would prefer some more discussion on that topic.

Comment: @W5VO - You have a valid point. I was thinking in terms of trying to reduce the profusion of tags but since there are many car type questions, it is probably better to keep them separate.

Comment: @W5VO - What about using the "remote-control" as general tag, and "WiFi" to further specify?

Comment: @stevenvh So what would the second tag be for the 27 MHz dedicated RC stuff? I don't have a good answer for that... They use various modulation schemes and there are multiple bands. Would you tag TV remotes "remote-control" and "infrared"?

Comment: @W5VO - I guess you're right.

Comment: That whole discussion probably deserves its own question, first we have to deal with RC.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, multifaceted approach here. Some of this might need to be updated later when we verify what we want to do with the tags that RC turn into.

### Manual Edit of Passive-Networks

Edit in [passive-networks](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-networks) for the questions which this fits. After this edit, we can make a nice tag wiki for [passive-networks](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-networks). This might not be the long term solution but was suggest and can be merged if we want to change the name later.

### Synonym made from RC to Remote-Control

Currently remote control usage is more common, so I suggest this as our synonym. We need to write a long clear tag wiki for RC which suggest [passive-networks](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-networks) if they are using resistor-capacitor.

We watch and see if we continue having issues with the wrong usage of this tag, in which case we can attempt a possible black list but I have a feeling this will clear it up.

Comment: I changed the resistor-capacitors into [tag:passive-networks]. 20 [tag:rc] remaining.

Comment: @stevenvh You might want to pretty up the tag wikis, I am heading to work. I have a couple synonyms you have suggested that might be worthy of posts also.

Comment: Since [tag:RC] is now a synonym for [tag:remote-control] I can't access it anymore; I'm automagically redirected to remote-control.

Comment: @stevenvh It automatically populates remote-control as the first option with RC and says at the bottom: "also: rc"

Comment: OK, I thought you wanted an excerpt for "rc", but I understand it takes care of itself.

Comment: @stevenvh I did not know the function well enough to know this would happen before now. We are both learning together. It looks like a good Remote-control except and wiki should get the job done, also one for passive-network if you have time.